# Reminders - DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model

Can Business Reminders be modeled as domain events even if there is no state change in the domain model?

for ex.

Sending notification to the customer that your password will be expired on so and so date?

Sending emails to customers that you should pay your dues timely else penalty will be charged **(Payment Dues Reminder)**

(We usually send these reminders before the deadline is reached)

Comment: "SendReminder" is a command, at least it will require to log/save the fact that the reminder was sent at a given time.

Comment: You may even consider that the reminder logic is a subdomain (a segregated or generic one) that has its proper state and aggregate to handle the tracking and retry issues

Answer (score 2):

Sending a **Reminder** is a **Service**. The fact that a **Reminder** was sent can be captured as a **DomainEvent**, but the actual sending of a **Reminder** is either an **ApplicationService** or **DomainService** depending of your application.

The **SendReminderService** should be called at specific points in time before the expiration period, so you will need a **Job Scheduler** that will either call this **Service** at specific intervals or send a **SendReminderForTodayCommand**.

You can model this by adding the concept of a **Reminder** explicitly and generate events when a reminder was sent. You will also need a **ScheduleReminderService**.

In the password example, you can schedule the **Reminder** when the **User** registers and when he changes his password.

Here's an example:

```
public class Reminder : Entity {

    public Details ReninderDetails { get; private set; }
    public Date SendAt { get; private set; }
    public bool WasSent { get; private set; }

    public void MarkAsSent() {

        WasSent = true;
        AddEvent(new ReminderSent(ReninderDetails));
    }
}

public class ScheduleReminderService {

    public void ScheduleReminder(Date remindAt) {

        var reminder = Reminder.ForDate(RremindAt);

        ReminderRepository.Add(reminder);
    }
}

public class SendRemindersService {

    public void SendReminders() {

        var reminders = ReminderRepository.GetScheduledReminders(Date.Today);

        foreach(var reminder in reminders) {          

            SendReminder(reminder);

            reminder.MarkAsSent();

            ReminderRepository.Save(reminder);
        }
    }
}
```